# How to sort a table by using dropdown menus (starting date - end date) for VueJS?

Tags: vuejs2

I am new to VueJS. How would I be able to sort a table using VueJS? I have four dropdown menus (to select starting month and starting year to an ending month and year) then display/update that to the table? I am grabbing data from a Sqlite database btw. My goal is to select a timeframe, then have it display in the table. I have been researching and watching videos on Youtube. But I have not been able to find a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<template>   <div class="time">
 <h2></h2>

 <center>

 <span>Select Timeframe: </span>
   <select v-model="startMonth">
     <option disabled value=" ">Month</option>
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
     <option>3</option>
     <option>4</option>
     <option>5</option>
     <option>6</option>
     <option>7</option>
     <option>8</option>
     <option>9</option>
     <option>10</option>
     <option>11</option>
     <option>12</option>
   </select>

    <select v-model="startYear">
     <option disabled value=" ">Year</option>
     <option>2017</option>
     <option>2018</option>
   </select> -

    <select v-model="endMonth">
     <option disabled value=" ">Month</option>
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
     <option>3</option>
     <option>4</option>
     <option>5</option>
     <option>6</option>
     <option>7</option>
     <option>8</option>
     <option>9</option>
     <option>10</option>
     <option>11</option>
     <option>12</option>
   </select>

    <select v-model="endYear">
     <option disabled value=" ">Year</option>
     <option>2017</option>
     <option>2018</option>
   </select>
   <button>Go</button> <br><br>
   <span>start: {{ startMonth }}</span>
   <span>{{ startYear }} - </span>
   <span>{{ endMonth }}</span>
   <span>{{ endYear }}</span>


   <table class = "table table-bordered table-sptried table-condensed">
   <thead>
             <tr>
                     <th>Month</th>
                     <th>Day</th>
                     <th>Year</th>
                     <th>Time</th>
                     <th>Activity</th>
             </tr>
   </thead>    
   <tbody>   
          <tr v-for="client in clients" :key="client.id">
             <td>{{client.Months}}</td>
             <td>{{client.Days}}</td>
             <td>{{client.year}}</td>
             <td>{{client.Time}}</td>
             <td>{{client.Activity}}</td>
         </tr>

 </tbody>
 </table> </center>   </div> </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Basic-Example) feature of Vue. Instead of reading directly from clients, you can create computed variable (for example `sortedClients`). Then you can do anything in this function

For example:

```
computed: {
  sortedClients: function() {
    function compare(a, b) {
      const aTime = <get time from a>
      const bTime = <get time from b>
      if (aTime < bTime)
        return -1;
      if (bTime > bTime)
        return 1;
      return 0;
    }

    return this.clients.sort(compare);
  }
}
```

For time conversion, you can use https://momentjs.com/